# Beautifulsoup to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

I found this sample code on a site and try to implement it according to how I want it to work. Unfortunately the original code works fine, there are multiple rows of scraped items but the one I've altered only insert 1 item.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql.cursors


html = urlopen("https://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-Computer-and-Networking-c-155.html")


bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
recordList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "wrap overflow", })


connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for record in recordList:
            title = record.find("span", {"class": 'title', }).get_text().strip()
            artist = record.find("span", {"class": "price wh_cn"}).get_text().strip()
            sql = "INSERT INTO `artist_song` (`artist`, `song`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (artist, title))
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Any errors that has been raised?

Comment: no error 

"Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: @Sean Francis N. Ballais anything ?

Comment: What's the output of `print(recordList)`?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais https://www.pastiebin.com/5af91f92cb4ff

Comment: Try `len(recordList)`. I think you only have one element in `recordList`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170979/discussion-between-reezal-aq-and-sean-francis-n-ballais).